# JSON File Parse Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

```
[{"cat1":136803,"cat2":"1.4545","cat3":"0.0885","cat4":"112969"},
 {"cat1":1564654,"cat2":"2.5448","cat3":"0.0568","cat4":"5468489"},
 {"cat1":5484654,"cat2":"1.8948","cat3":"0.0478","cat4":"898489"}]
```

I have a JSON structure that looks like the one above.

My code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('file/path') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

data["cat1"]
```

give me an error that list indicies must be integers not, str

How can I parse this to return only what I want, say "cat1"?

My goal is to parse out what I want from my JSON file and then write that to a CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried `data[0]["cat1"]`?

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON structure is a list of a dictionary. So, you have to write:

```
data[0]["cat1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values associated with the key `cat1`, try:

```
cat1 = [dct['cat1'] for dct in data]
```

Notice that `data` is a *list* of dicts, not a `dict` itself.
So you have to iterate through the items in the list (i.e. dicts) before you can access the values associated with the key `cat1`.